# For each span data get id and check id from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check any id sending with ajax and response json getting the id from json then checking if there is an id into span and then add it but is not working is always adding and adding more and more

Jquery

```
e.results.forEach(function(e) {
    var name = e.name;
    var id = e.id;
    if ($(".visitors span").length) {
        $('.visitors span').each(function() {
            var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            if (data_id != id) {
                $(".visitors").append("<span data-id='" + id + "'>" + name + "</span>");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".visitors").append("<span data-id='" + id + "'>" + name + "</span>");
    }
});
```

Comment: You are appending data-id = id, same id that you already have, so the .each will include that one too, and you will have infinite amount of span with that id.

Comment: I don't get it...

Comment: You are iterating "$('.visitors span')" but you are adding a new span into .visitors with ID you just received from your results, so you will iterate it again, and again and again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think your code is correct, but a suggestion: Instead of looping through the spans you're appending, just check if a span with a `data-id` exists (using [**CSS Attribute-Equal Selector**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp)), if not append a new span like this:

```
e.results.forEach(function(e) {
    var name = e.name;
    var id = e.id;

    var $span = $(".visitors span[data-id = '" + id + "']"); // select all the spans that have the data-id equal to id
    if (!$span.length) { // if there is none
        $(".visitors").append("<span data-id='" + id + "'>" + name + "</span>"); // then add a new one
    }
});
```